# Issue with php file not rendering html page, just the code written

Tags: php, xampp

I have a registration page written in HTML with some php code up in the beginning of the page, only renders the code written, not the webpage just plain text, will post photos as soon as I am home.

Reinstalled xammp to see if I had corrupt files.

no error code show or webpage just plain text of what I have written.

here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "style.css">
<script src="myFunction.js"></script>
<script src="video.js"></script>
<head>
<title>Young Theod - Moorish Music</title>
</head>
<main>
  <header>
    <p>
      <div class="logo">
    <img src="Mooringmusic.jpg" alt="Mooring Music" class="center">
  </div>
</p>
</header>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="home.html">Home</a>
      <a href="discography.html">Discography</a>
      <a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
      <a href="gallery.html">Galley</a>
      <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="list.html">Stay Updated</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <h5>Designed and maintained by Unsullied Technologies L.L.C ®</h5>
  <time></time>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, please wait until you have everything ready before asking a question - "will post photos as soon as I am home" - and screenshots are not very helpful; you need to share the actual code you are using. Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: This was just the start of it wanted to test the running of it still have to add more php code and the my other php scripts for connection to server do the same thing just displays the plain text not the actual function of the code.

Comment: If it is not from the extension, check your file encoding

Comment: @JoshuaT I do apologize, I sent on my lunch not near my computer and was trying to not let boss see I am programming at work.

Comment: @JessGabriel I have checked them and they do not kick back an error, could be compiler be causing the issues? I am using Xampp, I reinstalled it. Same issue

Comment: I am 99% sure that the issue comes from your file encoding. Instead of re_installing xampp everytime, change file encoding with your code editor to UTF8

Comment: @JessGabriel no i found the issue it was defaulting to a file versus viewing the encoding as a webpage changed the File:///c:/ to http://directory/file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Dharman
Was defaulting to the file not actual link of file to operation using the php protocol. changed from `File:///C:/....` to `Http://localhost/directory/file`